# Subgraphs of $K_6$ that satisfy $|V|=3$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many subgraphs $H=(V,E)$ of $K_6$ satisfy $|V|=3$? (If two subgraphs are isomorphic but have diffrent vertex sets, consider them distinct.)

We can choose the vertices as $\binom63$. My question is can I for theese $3$ vertices count all the subgraphs of $K_3$ or should they be non-isomorphic? If the should be non-isomorphic I get $4$ subgraphs and if they can be isomorphic the answer is $8$. What is correct?

Comment: My question is more precisly is the answer 4*C(6,3) or 8*C(6,3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that "isomorphic subgraphs with different vertex set are distinct" implies that the graph is *labelled*, i.e. you cannot permute vertices at all. It follows that the answer is $8\binom63$.